# Making button dock bottom

Tags: extjs

The button keeps being on top. How can I make it dock at the bottom

```
    <xsl:if test="@ISOFID=9051">
isoNS.PanelQDisableInfoMsg = Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
    title: 'Info', 
    width: 900,
    height: 250,
    modal: true,
    style: 'position: absolute; top: 100px;',
    id: 'infoWindow',
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    items: [

        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Ok',
            itemId: 'OkButton',
            docked: 'bottom'
        }
    ]   
}).show();</xsl:if>
```

According to suggestions here (and on google) I tried: `docked: 'bottom`, and:

```
   layout: {
        pack: 'bottom',
        type: 'hbox'
}
```

but these did not work for me. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Use `dockedItems` config for that. Documentation — http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-dockedItems

```
var panel = new Ext.panel.Panel({
fullscreen: true,
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [{
        text: 'Docked to the top'
    }]
}]
});
```